# I want to get a better understanding of imaplib

Tags: python, imaplib

I cannot find an appropriate guide for "How to use imaplib".

For example, when I want to move a message to the trash, I find the statement:

```
[Gmail]/Trash
```

Why not just "Trash"? What is the '[Gmail]' extension and how to use it?

Another example. For fetching information, I can do:

```
(BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)])
```

For getting the subject.

Or:

```
(RFC822)
```

For the whole message.

And another confusing thing is this 'labels' things. For example:

```
X-GM-MSGID
```

I don't understand what it stands for.

There are more labels etc. that I do not understand.

Can someone explain how to use the `imaplib` library to me?

Comment: every IMAP server can use different rules so maybe it is not easy to describe them all.

Comment: @furas good enough for me. tell me how to get the detailes about the imap server of google, and ill be good from there ;) Thanks for the message BTW

Comment: BTW: RFC822 is document which describe mail construction: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/

Comment: [Google Developers: IMAP extensions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions) - you can find `X-GM-MSGID` and there is link to [RFC3501](https://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc3501)

Comment: To know how to use imaplib with google I need to read the all RFC3501? There isnt any short version? this is a waste of time I think

Comment: this document is long and boring so nobody write tutorial :) You have to find out which elements you need at this moment and read only this part.

Comment: imaplib is a thin wrapper around IMAP.  To understand imaplib, you must understand imap.  To understand IMAP, you need to read RFC 3501.  It is long, but it is reasonably easy to read.